# C# Enhanced Listbox - remembers additional attributes after postback

Tags: c#, attributes, listbox

I'm in a situation where I need a listbox to remember after postback the attributes I've added to a number of the listitems in it. I found this solution online which appears to solve the issue but am not sure how to implement it.

[List box solution](http://blogs.delta-n.nl/dev/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=61dbd0ca-5c9f-4060-9d13-94177fe070a7&ID=85)

He says he wrote a class that inherits from Listbox which is fine, I've done that and have called it EnhancedListBox but how do I then apply that to the Listbox I'm using on the page?

I can't just substitute

```
<asp:ListBox >
```

with

```
<asp:EnhancedListBox>
```

but how else do I let the page know I want to use my inherited code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SaveViewState` and `LoadViewState` are virutal methods that you can override. What you want to try is creating "your own" `ListBox`:

```
class EnhancedListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override object SaveViewState() 
    {
        // code here from the tutorial
    }
    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        // code here from the tutorial
    }
}
```

This is also called ["Creating a custom control"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366537.aspx), it's very common to do it this way and it gives you great flexibility.

Comment: Have done the above code but don't know how to use it as a control on my page. I've tried building it in a seperate project and including the DLL (which seems like overkill but anyway). This doesn't seem to work as I'm getting an "Unknown server tag 'asp:EnhancedListBox'." error. Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes, have included the namespace correctly, not sure why it's giving me this error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a custom control for this
check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366537.aspx for the startup.